# CKEDITOR : Select text using start , end index position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

How do I select Particular text using text index position?

I have a para in editor and I just try to select select an Text using their index position's how can I do this?

Sample

```
<p>My Tes<b>ti</b>ng Point</p>
```

I wanted to select **Testing** using their index positions **4 and 11** .
And I'm using the below code to achieve this.But it isn't Working at all.

```
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
    range = editor.createRange();
    range.setStart(4);
    range.setEnd(11); 
    editor.getSelection().selectRanges([range]);
```

Please, anyone help me.

**Note:**

If I'm using **Text node** concept then the text shouldn't be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that CKEditor content is HTML data which is not flat, but has more like tree structure so it is not possible to simply set selection using only indexes.

As you can see in the docs for [`range.setStart`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-setStart) and [`range.setEnd`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dom.range-method-setEnd) it requires two parameters `startNode`/`endNode` and `startOffset`/`endOffset`. The offset is always set relatively to specific element, not absolute to the beginning of the content.

In your case, you should first find specific elements and then set offset relatively to those elements:

```
var editable = editor.editable(),
    startNode = editable.findOne( 'p' ),
    endNode = startNode,
    range = editor.createRange();

range.setStart( startNode.getChild( 0 ), 4 ); // Get first child which is text node "My Tes".
range.setEnd( endNode.getChild( 2 ), 2 ); // Get third child which is text node "ng Point".
editor.getSelection().selectRanges( [ range ] );
```